# How is the easiest way to sum 2 disjoint sets of Mongo documents from different databases?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have the same collection of documents, found in two different databases.
I would like to sum documents from both dbs. How is easiest to do? 
I need the sum of these sets, the sets are disjoint.

I assume that by using mongoimport, mongorestore but how exactly do you recommend dealing with the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it with mongodump, yes.

```
mongodump -d dbA
```

This will create some files in `dump/dbA`. Now run this command to import them into another db.

```
mongorestore -d dbB dump/dbA
```

You can run `mongorestore --help` for more info on its parameters.

Comment: But whether this will be the sum of these two sets?

Comment: Yes, it will append documents to the collection, unless you tell mongorestore to drop it before restoring.